# socket.emit from browser to browser not firing

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io

### socket.emit inside socket.on with angularjs is not firing

Here is my code

```
socket.emit('event1', 'event1 data');  // This is sent to nodejs server
socket.on('login', function(data) {   // This is triggered from Nodejs server
    if(with some condition) {
        socket.emit('event2', 'event2 data');  // This has to be sent to browsers,
                                               // but this is not firing
    }
});
```

event2 is **from browser** to **to browser** This is not firing up

This is my angular service

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('socket', function($rootScope) {
    var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.105:5000');
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {  
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        },
        ioemit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            console.log(io.sockets);
            io.sockets.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    };
});
```

I just tried something like io.sockets.emit but that doesn't help.. Any help is greatly appreciable

Comment: When you do this: `socket.emit('event2', 'event2 data'); `, it sends a message to your server, not to other clients.  So, your server would have to then send that message to the appropriate clients.  socket.io does NOT send client to client directly.  That's not what it does.  It sends from server to client or from client to server.

Comment: @jfriend00 any other alternatives?

Comment: If you have other reasons to have a socket.io connection to your server, it's only a few lines of code to teach the server how to forward a message from clientA to clientB.  You just need an identifier that clientA can use to indicate which other client it wants to send a message to and then the server just needs to be able to associate that identifier with clientB's socket.io connection.  Often you can use a username you already have or the `socket.id` that the server already knows as the identifier.

Comment: Browsers don't generally do peer-to-peer without an intermediary service because both clients are behind a firewall so it's tricky to establish a connection between them without using an intermediate server.

Comment: @jfriend00 that makes sense.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
socket.emit('event2', 'event2 data');
```

it sends a message to your server, not to other clients. So, your server would have to then send that message to the appropriate clients. socket.io does NOT send client to client directly. That's not what it does. It sends from server to client or from client to server.

If you have other reasons to have a socket.io connection to your server, it's only a few lines of code to teach the server how to forward a message from clientA to clientB. You just need an identifier that clientA can use to indicate which other client it wants to send a message to and then the server just needs to be able to associate that identifier with clientB's socket.io connection. Often you can use a username you already have or the `socket.id` that the server already knows as the identifier.

Browsers don't generally do peer-to-peer without an intermediary service helping them because both clients are usually behind a firewall so it's tricky to establish a connection between them without using an intermediate server.  Web browsers do support webRTC which is a peer-to-peer scheme, but there still needs to be a server involved to facilitate the direct client-to-client connection.  If you want to know more about webRTC, here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Z2PDsqgJP8) on how it works.  If you already have a socket.io connection to your server and your data isn't super real-time (like voice chat or video chat), then it's probably just easier to use the server to forward messages over socket.io from clientA to clientB.

Comment: is this supported in client side `socket.removealllisteners()`

Comment: @overflow - I don't know.  It's not listed in the client-side doc.  If it was, it would probably be different caps: `socket.removeAllListeners()`.  Not sure what this has to do with the question, though.

Comment: @overflow - Looking at the client-side code, it does not look like it supports `socket.removeAllListeners()`.  `.on()` returns an object that has a `.destroy()` method that can be used to remove a single listener.  You could create your own method that would keep track of all the `.on()` calls and call destroy on all of them.